# How to parse XML and store as a list ( python)

Tags: python, xml, excel, elementtree

Im sorry have to ask again.

I want to convert xml file to excel by `xml.etree.ElementTree`.

Assume my **xml** looks like :

> ```
> <ParameterCluster>
>           <Name>AAAAAA</Name>
>           <ParameterDefinitionList>
>             <ParameterDefinition>
>               <Name>LengthMin</Name>
>               <Type>UInt8</Type>
>             </ParameterDefinition>
>             <ParameterDefinition>
>               <Name>LengthMax</Name>
>               <Type>UInt8</Type>
>             </ParameterDefinition>
>           </ParameterDefinitionList>
>
>           <VariantImlementationList>
>             <VariantImlementation>
>               <MajorVariantList>
>                 <MajorVariant>A_Basis</MajorVariant>
>               </MajorVariantList>
>               <MinorVariantList>
>                         <ParameterValue>
>                           <ValueList>
>                             <Value>47</Value>
>                           </ValueList>
>                           <ValueList>
>                             <Value>80</Value>
>                           </ValueList>
>                         </ParameterValue>
>               </MinorVariantList>
>               <MajorVariantList>
>                 <MajorVariant>B_Basis</MajorVariant>
>                 <MajorVariant>C_Basis</MajorVariant>
>               </MajorVariantList>
>               <MinorVariantList>
>                         <ParameterValue>
>                           <ValueList>
>                             <Value>47</Value>
>                           </ValueList>
>                           <ValueList>
>                             <Value>40</Value>
>                           </ValueList>
>                         </ParameterValue>
>               </MinorVariantList> 
>             </VariantImlementation>
>           </VariantImlementationList>
>         </ParameterCluster>
> ```

That means, I have `3` basis (`A_basis`, `B_basis`, `C_basis`).

And in `A_ Basis`, the Value of `LengthMin` is `47` and Value of `LengthMax` is `80`.

But in `B_basis` and `C_Basis`. the Value of `LengthMin` is `47` and Value of `LengthMax` is `40`.

So I want to get something like :

```
{'AAAAAA','LengthMin','UInt8','A_Basis',47}
{'AAAAAA','LengthMax','UInt8','A_Basis',80}
{'AAAAAA','LengthMin','UInt8','B_Basis',47}
{'AAAAAA','LengthMax','UInt8','B_Basis',40}
{'AAAAAA','LengthMin','UInt8','C_Basis',47}
{'AAAAAA','LengthMax','UInt8','C_Basis',40}
```

Then I can write it into excel file. Is that possible to get that kind of list?

Comment: are you sure this is valid XML? E.g fist <MinorVariantList> isn't closed.

Comment: Hi Andrej Kesely. I'm sorry Today is my first day use stackoverflow. I've change it in my Question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For parsing XML you can use `BeautifulSoup` instead of `xml.etree.ElementTree` (the interface is more intuitive).

The parsing is straightforward (assuming length of `ParameterValue` is always the same as `ParameterValue.ValueList`: Firstly you need to extract the the parameter types, and then iterate over all `<MajorVariant>` and populate result list.

If BeautifulSoup isn't a problem, here is example code:

```
data = """<ParameterCluster>
              <Name>AAAAAA</Name>
              <ParameterDefinitionList>
                <ParameterDefinition>
                  <Name>LengthMin</Name>
                  <Type>UInt8</Type>
                </ParameterDefinition>
                <ParameterDefinition>
                  <Name>LengthMax</Name>
                  <Type>UInt8</Type>
                </ParameterDefinition>
              </ParameterDefinitionList>

              <VariantImlementationList>
                <VariantImlementation>
                  <MajorVariantList>
                    <MajorVariant>A_Basis</MajorVariant>
                  </MajorVariantList>
                  <MinorVariantList>
                            <ParameterValue>
                              <ValueList>
                                <Value>47</Value>
                              </ValueList>
                              <ValueList>
                                <Value>80</Value>
                              </ValueList>
                            </ParameterValue>
                  </MinorVariantList>
                  <MajorVariantList>
                    <MajorVariant>B_Basis</MajorVariant>
                    <MajorVariant>C_Basis</MajorVariant>
                  </MajorVariantList>
                  <MinorVariantList>
                            <ParameterValue>
                              <ValueList>
                                <Value>47</Value>
                              </ValueList>
                              <ValueList>
                                <Value>40</Value>
                              </ValueList>
                            </ParameterValue>
                  </MinorVariantList>
                </VariantImlementation>
              </VariantImlementationList>
            </ParameterCluster>"""


from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pprint import pprint

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'xml')

name, types = soup.select_one('Name'), []
for n, t in zip(soup.select('ParameterDefinitionList Name'), soup.select('ParameterDefinitionList Type')):
    types.append([name.text, n.text, t.text])

rv = []
for major, minor in zip(soup.select('MajorVariantList'), soup.select('MajorVariantList ~ MinorVariantList')):
    for mj in major.select('MajorVariant'):
        for i, mn in enumerate(minor.select('Value')):
            rv.append(types[i] + [mj.text, mn.text])

pprint(rv, width=120)
```

Output:

```
[['AAAAAA', 'LengthMin', 'UInt8', 'A_Basis', '47'],
 ['AAAAAA', 'LengthMax', 'UInt8', 'A_Basis', '80'],
 ['AAAAAA', 'LengthMin', 'UInt8', 'B_Basis', '47'],
 ['AAAAAA', 'LengthMax', 'UInt8', 'B_Basis', '40'],
 ['AAAAAA', 'LengthMin', 'UInt8', 'C_Basis', '47'],
 ['AAAAAA', 'LengthMax', 'UInt8', 'C_Basis', '40']]
```

Comment: Thank you Andrej Kesely. I'm now install BeautifulSoup & pprint package .I'll try it in my script.  It's awesome , thank you. Have a nice day.

Comment: Hi Andrej Kesely. I write my script as : 
`infile = open("ALL.xml","r")`
`contents = infile.read()`
`soup = BeautifulSoup(contents,'xml')` 
then this error gives out : **UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 2034240: character maps to <undefined>**
Im sorry Idont have any idea about this.. Do you ever face it before?

Comment: @syo that is encoding eroor, your file probably contains some strange characters. Look around StackOverflow how to properly decode/encode the string.

Comment: Hi Andrej Kesely . It worked out and looks really nice. Thank you & sorry for late feedback. Nice day.